# Include fluentd time into json post data

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, fluent

td-agent.config

```
<match test>
 type webhdfs
 host localhost
 port 50070
 path /test/%Y%m%d_%H
 username hdfs
 output_include_tag false
 remove_prefix test
 time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
 output_include_time true
 format json
 localtime
 buffer_type file
 buffer_path /test/test
 buffer_chunk_limit 4m
 buffer_queue_limit 50
 flush_interval 3s
</match>
```

In hdfs log file it show as below:

```
2016-02-22 16:04:15   {"login_id":123,"email":"abcd@gmail.com"}
```

Have any way to  **embed the fluentd time field** not the client time into json data before store in file such as:

```
{"time_key":"2016-02-22 16:04:15","login_id":123,"email":"abcd@gmail.com"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution :

Use plugin https://github.com/repeatedly/fluent-plugin-record-modifier

Add the field time and then push to hdfs

:)